# Proving that between each pair of vertices there is a path length $2$ at most

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph with $n$ vertices such that $\forall v,w\in V$ that doesn't have a common edge we have: $\text{deg}(v)+\text{deg}(w)\ge n-1$.
>
> Prove that for each pair of vertices there is a path of length 2 at most.

From the pigeon hole principle, there are more than $n-1$ edges from $v,w$ and there are another $n-2$ vertices so there is at least one common vertex that $v$ and $w$ has an edge with.

My problem is now since we know $v,w$ are connected with another vertex, and since both of them have more edges, then there is a path of length more than $2$.

So is there actually a problem with this question?

Comment: You are done. Either $v=w$ and there is a path of length $0$; or $v,w$ have a common edge and there is a path of length $1$; or - as you showed - they have a common neighbour $u$ and $vuw$ is a path of length $2$.

Comment: You're _not_ asked to show that there aren't paths of length $3$ or more. That's not what they ask about. The question is "is there a path of length at most 2?" and you've shown that yes, there is.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen that covers all the vertices? it's kinda hard to believe that there aren't any pair of vertices with only paths of more than 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v, w \in V$.  Then we have three cases:

**Case 1**: $v = w$

Trivially, this means that there is a path of length zero from $v$ to $w$.

**Case 2**: $v \neq w$, there is an edge between $v$ and $w$.

By definition, this means that there is a path of length $1$ between $v$ and $w$.

**Case 3**: $v \neq w$, there is no edge between $v$ and $w$.

By the hypothesis, $\text{deg}(v) + \text{deg}(w) \geq n -1$.  Since there are only $n - 2$ vertices in $V\setminus\{v,w\}$, the pigeonhole principle states that at least one vertex must be counted in both $\text{deg}(v)$ and $\text{deg}(w)$.  This means that there is a vertex $u$ s.t. $(v,u) \in E$ and $(u,w) \in E$.  Thus, we have the path of length $2$: $v \to u \to w$, completing the proof.